# Use a Script in Automator to classify files in a directory structure YYYY-MM-DD, getting it from their filenames

Tags: bash, macos, shell, automator

Having thousands of pictures and videos without meta-data date, but with the date structure at their name (ex: YYYYMMDD_HHMMSS.jpg), want to classify them in folders with their date, YYYY-MM-DD.

The idea is to use an action folder in Automator, so when I add pictures there, they classify automatically.

I tried with this code inside Automator, but it doesn't do anything even if doesn't give errors:

```
dest_dir=/Users/..........
# pattern to grab 4 digits of year 2 digits of month and 2 of the day
file_pattern="_([[:digit:]]{4})([[:digit:]]{2})([[:digit:]]{2})"
for file in test_file_*; do
  [[ ! -f $file ]] && continue  # look at regular files only
  if [[ $file =~ $file_pattern ]]; then
    year="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
    month="${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
    day="${BASH_REMATCH[3]}"
    destination_dir="$dest_dir/$year-$month-$day"
    [[ ! -d $destination_dir ]] && mkdir -p "$destination_dir"
    echo "Moving $file to $destination_dir"
    mv "$file" "$destination_dir"
  fi
done
```

[The code on Automator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uBoKG.png)
[Example of the structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5UME4.png)

Answer (score 0):

You almost had it. You were checking the part AFTER the `_` in the filename. My updated example has the right fields checked:

**Update 0:** Applied fixes to script from feedback.

**Update 1:** The script was tested as working under Bash 3.2.57. No need for Homebrew.

```bash
dest_dir=/Users/myuser/photo-archive
# Note: Change `*.jpg` to `*.{jpg,mp4}` to also categorize videos
for file in /path/to/photos/*.jpg; do
  [[ -f $file ]] || continue  # look at regular files only
  filebase=$(basename -- "$file")
  if [[ $filebase =~ ^([[:digit:]]{4})([[:digit:]]{2})([[:digit:]]{2}) ]]; then
    year=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
    month=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
    day=${BASH_REMATCH[3]}
    destination_dir=$dest_dir/$year-$month-$day
    mkdir -p "$destination_dir"
    echo "Moving $file to $destination_dir"
    mv "$file" "$destination_dir"
  fi
done
```

Also, `mkdir -p` won't fail or warn if the directory already exists. Part of what's nice about it.

Also also, in the form `var=$other_var` double-quotes are not necessary unless the line contains a literal space, i.e. `var="$foo $bar"`.

### OSX runs Bash from 17 years ago

AFAIK Mac OSX still only ships with Bash 3.2 which came out 2006-10-11 (OSX users should use [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) to install Bash 5).

<s>I'm not entirely certain this script not working is caused directly by this</s> **(Edit: it's not, I tested it)**, but it's something you're going to have to get used to if you continue to use OSX and write Bash scripts that work in OSX.

To work around the fact that OSX *still* hasn't updated the Bash version they give you in **17 goddamn years and counting**, to write the script so that it should call the newer version of Bash installed from Homebrew, use this as your bangline:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! We are so close :)
I understand the updates but could it be that it doesn't work because it must be: test_file* instead of: test_file_* because the names are without _ at the end? (ex: YYYYMMDD_HHMMSS.mp4) 
Or something similar, because I get no error, but it doesn't create the folders...

Comment: thanks again for your help. 
I still couldn't make it work so I still need help. 
I'm using your code. I also tried adding the destiny before (dest_dir=/Users/...), the Shell: /bin/bash and data as Argument, but even if I do not get errors, it doesn't move or do anything. I don't really know where could be the issue. Any idea?

Comment: You were right, the regex was wrong based on the filename pattern your question - fixed. I also fixed the `for file in test_file_*` line. That glob (`test_file_*) would never pick up on a file named `20240204_123456.jpg`.
Let me know if that fixes your issues.

Comment: Change the `*.jpg` to `*.jpg *.mp4` if you also have videos you want to categorize.

Comment: Thanks again amphetamachine for your help. I tried with your changes but still doesn't do anything and I really do not understand. I tried also with an * where the jpg extension just in case, but nothing. I checked all the code because it's very clear, but there is still something and I have no idea. Dest_dir is ok, the for is well closed, the if also... Any other idea?

Comment: Updated my answer to reflect the fact you're running on OSX. tl;dr, change the bangline.

Comment: Wow, you are right, it's crazy that Apple do not update it. People can get crazy with this little things. Trying to fix it I wrote the bangline you wrote at the beginning of the code, but I still do not get any result. ¿Do you think I should create a new question as it is a new issue? I did **cd /usr/bin/** and I can get there, but **cd /usr/bin/env/** it says not such file or directory even if I can see it from /bin. Maybe it's something of rights? I'm sorry for bothering you

Comment: What's the output from the command `type -ap bash` and `bash --version`?

Comment: GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin22)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

Comment: What's the output from the command `type -ap bash`

Comment: bash is /bin/bash

Comment: Okay, you're likely going to have to install [Homebrew](https://brew.sh) on your mac in order to get this to work. I don't run a mac anymore, but Homebrew will then install Bash 5, allowing newer Bash features to work. In the mean time, I'll try to re-write my script so it works in Bash 3.2.

Comment: The script works as-is in Bash 3.2. No need for Homebrew. The `for file in *.jpg` will pick up jpeg files in the current directory only. How are you executing it -- what's `pwd` say when you're running it, and are there jpeg files in that directory?

Comment: I hope I didn't break anything... I tried to install it, but it showed a few errors:
- fatal: couldn't find remote ref refs/heads/master
- Fetching /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/heroku/homebrew-brew failed! 
- Some taps failed to update! The following taps can not read their remote branches:   heroku/brew

Later asked me to do "brew tap --repair" but I don't know if I have to reinstall it again, because still doesn't work

Comment: It's okay, homebrew as it turns out isn't necessary. I tested the script under Bash 3.2 like you have by default in OSX and it works (for me at least).

Comment: Sorry, as I execute it on Automator, and I have the **dest_dir=/Users/...** at the beginning of the code, I do not understand why do we need to do **pwd** before. I guess if we point to the folder where I put the images and videos it's fine, right? By now I'm trying with .jpg and .mp4 files.

Comment: Oh, that's a simple solution. I updated my script, instead of `for file in *.jpg` it's `for file in /path/to/photos/*.jpg` and using the file's basename for the regex match.

Comment: I changed it but still not doing anything. 
I have at the beginning `#!/usr/bin/env bash` , later `dest_dir=/Users/route_to_organize`and after that the rest of your code. If it doesn't work... could it be because I tried to install **Homebrew**?

Comment: You have to change `/path/to/photos` to your actual photo directory.

Comment: Yes, yes, I did. I changed it to the path where I drop the pictures and videos and where Automator should pic them to execute it, but... nothing. Is there any way to see what is going on?

Comment: Can I do a test with just a part instead of everything to see if it reaches them and to see what is not working?

Comment: `#!/usr/bin/env bash`
`dest_dir=/Users/...` 
`for file in /Users/.../*.jpg; do` 
`mkdir -p /Users/..../"hello"` 
`done`-> it creates the folder, so that is working

Comment: Any other idea or test that I could do? :)